# How can i rewrite this program so that it will print the value of text in reverse order

Tags: turbo-c++, turbo-c

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

char text[]="A nut for a jar of tuna";
int txtposition,txtlength;

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    txtlength=Strlen(text);

    for(txtposition=0; txtposition<=txtlength;txtposition++)
     { 
         cout<<text[txtposition]; 
     }
getch();
}
```

How to rewrite this program so that it print the value of text in reverse order?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Change `for` loop: `for (txtposition = txtlength - 1; txtposition >= 0; txtposition--)`

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged as a C++ question

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh i see thank you :D

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh hi could you please explain how you obtained that answer?

Comment: @aspiring programmer: It is simple. `text` is an array of `char`. In C/C++, first element of array is indexed by 0 and last element is indexed by `length - 1`, `length` is the length of array. Now, we just print the `char` array from last element to first element, we have a text with reverse order. So, in `for` loop, let index at last element, decrease index by 1, and end the loop when index is smaller first element's index, for each step of the loop, just print char at index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

char text[]="A nut for a jar of tuna";
int txtposition,txtlength;

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    txtlength=Strlen(text);

    for(txtposition= txtlength-1 ; txtposition>=0;txtposition--)
     { 
         cout<<text[txtposition]; 
     }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either go with the answer suggested by @Prashant or you create another `char reversetext[]` where you can save your reverse text. That way you can use it as per your needs.

Also, if you are trying to reverse each word, a different longer algorithm is required. Let me know if you are looking for that.